# Why is MRJob sorting my keys?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mrjob

I'm running a fairly big MRJob job (1,755,638 keys) and the keys are being written to the reducers in sorted order. This happens even if I specify that Hadoop should use the hash partitioner, with:

```
class SubClass(MRJob):

    PARTITIONER = "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.HashPartitioner"

...
```

I don't understand why the keys are sorted, when I am not asking for them to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are not sorted by default, but the HashPartitioner will give the *appearance* of sorting keys if the dataset is small. When I increased the size of the dataset from 50M to 10G the keys stopped being sorted.

Comment: What kind of hash is that when it gives the appearance of sorting!?!

Comment: Don't know. Perhaps it wasn't even bothering to sort, given how small my "fairly big MRJob" actually was.

Answer (score 2):

The [HashPartitioner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/HashPartitioner.html) is used by default when you don't specify any partitioner explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

MR sorts the key/value pairs by key so that it can ensure that all values for a given key are passed to the reducer together.  In fact, the Iterable passed into the reduce() method just reads that sorted list until it finds a new key and then it stops iterating.  That's why the keys will always appear in order.

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in the documents?
Your answer is in contradiction with @vy32!

Comment: @Dandelion The sort is not done by the partitioner, which determines which partition each key/value pair goes to.  The sort happens as part of the reducer pre-processing so that key/values are grouped together to be passed to the reducer together.